# О классификации числительных по грамматическому признаку

Tags: грамматика, морфология, числительные

В соответствии с **Грамматикой-80** к классу **грамматических числительных** относятся только **количественные и собирательные** числительные. Другие слова с количественным значением (в том числе порядковые числительные)  туда не входят.

В школе используется **упрощенная классификация** числительных по семантическому (смысловому)  признаку.

(1) К числительным относятся **все слова** с количественно-числовым или счетно-порядковым значением, при этом они делятся **на три группы:** количественные, порядковые и собирательные.

(2) **Существительные** с количественным значением: тысяча, миллион, миллиард и **счетно-местоименное** слово один входят в разряд количественных числительных.

(3) **Прилагательные** со счетно-порядковым значением (**порядковые числительные**): первый, второй.

(4) К количественным числительным также примыкают **дробные числительные**, которые с точки зрения грамматики являются **словосочетаниями**.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html

**Вопросы**

(1) Как можно объяснить **грамматическую** классификацию числительных? В ее основе  лежит **"ГЛАВНОЕ ПРАВИЛО"** для числительных, о котором часто забывают. **А какое это правило?**

(2) Что нового в этой теме в современной лингвистике?

(3) **Какой классификацией** и почему пользуетесь вы?  Нужна ли нам именно **упрощенная** классификация?

(4) Насколько понятна вам тема, связанная с числительными, какие трудности она вызывает? Ваше **личное мнение** (то есть практика) не менее важно, чем знание теории вопроса. (Пусть его учтут **составители новых учебников** по правописанию.)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html

> В особую часть речи – имя числительное – выделяются только те количественные и собирательные слова, которые обладают своими собственными **морфологическими** признаками, не позволяющими объединить их ни с существительными, ни с прилагательными

На этом основании **миллион** и **ноль** относят к существительным, а не числительным.

А в чем же морфологическая разница между словом **семь** и словом **миллион**?
Почему **семь** не существительное? Да на самом деле причин не так уж и много, их практически нет. Можно сослаться на отсутствие рода, но будем просто считать, что **семь** среднего рода. Можно сослаться на отсутствие числа (сравните: **много миллионов**, **много семь**, **много семерок**). Можно сослаться, что тип склонений по падежам у **семи** отличается от 3 стандартных типов склонений существительных. Ну так просто назовем его 4-ым типом склонения.

Кстати, у числительного **семь** есть существительное- двойник - **семерка**.

Правда, есть еще различие синтаксической связи у числительного с существительным относительно связи существительного с существительным:

```
Семь столов   // управление
Семи столов   // согласование
Семи столам   // согласование
Семью столами // согласование

Миллион столов    // управление
Миллиона столов   // управление
Миллиону столов   // управление
Миллионом столов  // управление
```

Видим, что числительное все же отличается **грамматикой** от существительных. Видимо это и называют главным грамматическим правилом у числительных:

> Характерной синтаксической особенностью количественных и собирательных числительных является специфическое противопоставление образуемых ими сочетаний в формах им. и вин. п. и в формах др. косв. падежей: в формах им. и вин. п. числительное (количественное и собирательное) управляет неодушевл. существительным в форме род. п.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение и внимание к вопросу, мой голос за это.  А ответ такой: все дело в главном правиле для грамматических числительных. Это правило вам и многим другим, конечно, ИЗВЕСТНО, но оно всегда остается В СТОРОНЕ от внимания пользователей. Так какое это правило?

Comment: Обновил. Хотя возможно под главным правилом имеют в виду правило составления числительных друг из друга.

Comment: Да. именно это правило отличает грамматические числительные от других слов с количественным значением, которые ведут себя как существительные или прилагательные. Я подожду другие ответы, если они будут, но по этому разделу в принципе  готова принять ваш ответ.